# can't find function arguments in clause Error: operator is not a function

Tags: sml

I have these two function...

```
fun lessThan (a, b) (c, d) = if ((real a) / (real b)) < ((real c) / (real d)) then true else false;



fun test = lessThan( (4,2) (3,2) );
```

when I try to compile, I get the error stated in the title. Why can't I call lessThan like this? When I run it from the sml console as: "lessThan (4,2) (3,2)", I get false, which is correct.

Comment: I realize if i put a dummy argument in fun test, i eliminate the first error such as: fun test L = lessThan ( (4,2) (3,2) );

Comment: You can't define a function that doesn't take any argument in SML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error you experience is caused by `test` being defined as a function without an argument.

Another error is that `lessThan( (4,2) (3,2) )` has a set of parentheses too much.

This is probably caused by the misconception that "to call a function, you must first name the function, and then put the arguments in parenthesis". This is true for a lot of languages like C, Java and Python, but it is not the case in SML.

The syntactically valid way to test this function is:

```
val test = lessThan (4,2) (3,2)
```

And one approach to avoiding this type of error is: Never have any redundant parentheses. A parenthesis is redundant if having it does not actually change the result. So `((1) + ((1)))` is full of redundant ones, whereas `lessThan (4,2) (3,2)` has no redundant parentheses, since they are all used for constructing tuples.

---

As for the function itself, you could indent it so that it becomes easier to read, and you could remove those redundant parentheses:

```
fun lessThan (a, b) (c, d) =
    if real a / real b < real c / real d
    then true
    else false;
```

Notice also that `if p then true else false` is just a wordy way to say `p`.

So an even shorter version of this function:

```
fun lessThan (a, b) (c, d) =
    real a / real b < real c / real d
```

You could argue that an extra set of parentheses improves readability:

```
fun lessThan (a, b) (c, d) =
    (real a / real b) < (real c / real d)
```

but considering your problem of not knowing when it's okay to place parentheses, I would argue that never placing any you don't need is a good exercise before you think of adding ones entirely for readability.